# Sass Loader for webpack: How to get CSS file instead of inline styles?

Tags: css, webpack, sass, stylesheet

I'm using webpack for my JS and SASS and it works. But now I want the CSS as a standalone stylesheet file and not as inline styles. What do I have to change in my webpack settings to achieve this?

Here is my current summarized webpack config:

```
{
    entry: {
        'plugin': './src/js/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader",
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

I've used the official docs of [SASS Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#examples) and I know from the [Style Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#url) docs that I've to use the File Loader too.  But I'm at the end of my knowledge and need your help. All my trail-and-error configs failed.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install `mini-css-extract-plugin` to be able to remove css from js files and put them into separated .css files.

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin'); // <--- INSTALL THIS
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'plugin': './src/js/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugin: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working now and I have a standalone CSS file now. But how do I get this CSS file as loaded stylesheet and part of my build?

Comment: you have to manually add them, or add html-webpack-plugin to the build

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: There is only one answer for this question and not much explanation to be done. It is like a cake recipe, you just have to have things there.